# How to specify a range with a relative cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I frequently have a "total" cell that should simply sum up all cells above it in the same column. Easy enough, but I also frequently add rows above that total, then have to manually update the total range to include those new cells.

```
  A    
1 10
2 20
3 30
=SUM(A1:A3)
```

When I add 3 rows above the "total" cell, I also have to remember to update the SUM formula to =SUM(A1:A6).

```
  A
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
6 60
=SUM(A1:A3) *X INCORRECT. Does not include A4:A6*
```

Is there a way to define the formula as =SUM(A1:"The cell directly above this one") ? I have looked into INDIRECT(R[-1]C[0]), but mixing that notation with A1 notation, of course, results in an error: `=SUM(A1:INDIRECT(R[-1]C[0]))`. Is there a better approach, or am I simply mis-using the notation?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1))
```